# Add a word at the end of URLs

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add a word at the end of all URLs in a String (a lot of URLs)

Example

```
$wordToAdd = "/Sunday"

$StringBefore = "hello word1 href=""https://youtube.ca/aaa"" hello word2 href=""https://google.com/aaa"" "

$StringAfter = "hello word1 href=""https://youtube.ca/aaa/Sunday"" hello word2 href=""https://google.com/aaa/Sunday"""
```

Help please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution will work on PowerShell (v3 or higher) or PowerShell Core.

```
$wordToAdd = "/Sunday"
$StringBefore = "hello word1 href=""https://youtube.ca/aaa"" hello word2 href=""https://google.com/aaa"" "

$StringBefore -replace '(?<=href="+)(?<uri>[^"]+)',"`${uri}$wordToAdd"
```

**Explanation:**

`-replace` uses regex matching followed by a string and regex capture group replacement. Here is the regex matching breakdown:

- `(?<=href="+)`: Uses a positive lookbehind assertion `(?<=)` for literal string `href=` and `"` one or more times (`+`).
- `(?<uri>[^"]+)`: Uses a named capture group `(?<uri>)` to match non-double quotes `[^"]` one or more times.
- `${uri}`: The syntax required to access capture group `uri`. Note the backtick escape because it ***is not a variable*** so we want PowerShell to not interpolate. This value must be inside by single quotes or double quotes with the `$` escaped.

---

In PowerShell v6 or higher, you can use scriptblock substitution.

```
$StringBefore -replace '(?<=href="+)[^"]+',{$_.ToString() + $wordToAdd}
```

Here `$_` is the `Match` object. The `ToString()` method returns the match as a string so we can easily concatenate another string (`$wordToAdd`) to it.

---

If all of your URIs in the string always have the same protocol, you can make your regex string simpler.

```
$StringBefore -replace 'https://[^"]+',"`$&$wordToAdd"
```